# psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near '

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sql-insert, psycopg2

I would like to add new message in my table 'message': d'eau , but I recieved this error:
(p.s I don't have error when I add another message like 'problème' or another type of accents)
How can Solve it?

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "eau"
LINE 1: ...essage (message, published_on, active) VALUES ('d'eau',NOW()...
                                                             ^
```

That my Function:

```
def post_new_message():
    ConnexionDB()

    message = request.form["message"]
    sql_set_all_message_to_false = "UPDATE message SET active = False"
    DB_Protocole.cur.execute(sql_set_all_message_to_false)
    DB_Protocole.conn.commit()
    sql_insert_message = "INSERT INTO message (message, published_on, active) VALUES ('"+message+"',NOW(),True)"
    DB_Protocole.cur.execute(sql_insert_message)
    DB_Protocole.conn.commit()
    DeconnexionDB()

    return redirect(url_for("get_message"))
```

Comment: Please have a look at the docs, how to pass varaibles to queries: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: See [the documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html) on how to parameterize a query. Please pay special attention to the first red box in the page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to write the message in the query text itself enclosed in simple quotes. It is bad because it has been a source for SQL injection attacks for decades, and the recommended way is to use parameterized queries.

But here when your text contains a simple quote like `"d'eau"`, the query string ends in:

```
...VALUES('d'eau',...)
```

At least it should have been `...VALUES('d''eau',...)` doubling the offending quote. This is the reason for the error.

For all that reasons, you should use a parameterized query:

```
DB_Protocole.cur.execute("INSERT INTO message (message, published_on, active) VALUES (?,NOW(),True)", [message])
```